# Estimation of power of number by its factorial

Tags: calculus, estimation

Let $a \in R$, such as $a>1$. How to find smallest natural number $N$, such that $a^N < N!$?

Comment: Stirling's formula. For $n>0$ we have $N!=(N/e)^N\sqrt {2\pi N}\;(1+d_N)$ where $0<d_N<1/6N.$   So $a^N<N! \iff a<N!^{1/N}=(N/e)(2\pi N)^{1/2N}(1+d_n)^{1/N}$.

Comment: This formula gives nothing about $N$

Answer (score 2):

In fact [@Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel) has found a formula to the sequence.

---

A small check of the smallest $N$ for $a =1,2,\cdots 10$ gives us the [sequence $A065027$ in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A065027) giving us the smallest $N >0$ such that $a^N <N! $.

---

He writes that it appears that $L(n) < a(n) - n e + \log{\sqrt{2 \pi n)}} < \frac {1}{2} $,  where $L(n) = -\frac {1}{2} + o(1)$ , and $L(n) > -0.53$ for all $n$.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is interesting idea, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

by taking the logarithm on both sides we obtain
$$N\ln(a)<\ln(N!)$$ from here we get
$$\ln(a)<\frac{\ln(N!)}{N}$$ thus we get $$a<e^{\frac{\ln(N!)}{N}}$$

Comment: I think that the OP has a $!$ as a factorial,though I'm not sure.

Comment: yes ok i have corrected it

Comment: Even with an edit this doesn't really help. You can estimate an $a$ given an $N$, but OP is asking the reverse of that.

Comment: one can solve the reverse of this problem only by a numerical method